# "current month" and "cumulative monthly expenditure" data within the same query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Working in MS ACCESS, I am trying to query the Table_projFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure field in terms of both "current month" (Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure) and "cumulative monthly expenditure" (Sum(Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure) AS CumExp) data within the same query with no success. Please see the below SQL code.

Here I tried to use the scalar method but it only filtered the data to the first date range in the sub query. The HAVING statement at the bottom of the code had no bearing on the results.

Thanks in advance for your input.

---

```
SELECT 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.SLIN_Number, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.ACRN, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.FundingReceived, 
    Sum(Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure) AS CumExp, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyHoursCharged, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.ProjectName, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.FwdFundingPlan, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.FY15FundingPlan, 
    Sum(Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure) AS SumOfMonthlyExpenditure1, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure
FROM 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery
WHERE 
    (
        ((Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure) In 
            (SELECT 
                Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure
            FROM 
                Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery
            WHERE 
                Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthEndDate BETWEEN #10/01/2014# AND #11/01/2014#
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.SLIN_Number, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.ACRN, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.FundingReceived, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyHoursCharged, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.ProjectName, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.FwdFundingPlan, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.FY15FundingPlan, 
    Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure
HAVING 
    (
        ((Sum(Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure)) In 
            (SELECT 
                Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthlyExpenditure
            FROM 
                Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery
            WHERE 
                Table_ProjFunding_ActionQuery.MonthEndDate <= Now()
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Could you please show some sample data and the output you hope to see please?

Comment: First, your subqueries in the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses are entirely redundant as all fields derive from same table `Table_ProjFunding_ActingQuery`. Simply use the subquery's `WHERE` statement as the main query's `WHERE` statement. FYI - you can specify in these sections fields that are not aggregated. Second, what are you attempting in the `HAVING` clause as you want to have your aggregate monthly expenditure equal to original level monthly expenditure?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I provided a more concise question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636048/displaying-running-sum-by-product.