# Displaying Running sum by product #

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've posted a couple of question on this site regarding this topic and I thank you for your input. I decided to take a step back and see if I can rephrase my question a bit better.

The below code provides a Running sum across various product numbers. Unfortunately, it provides a running total regardless of the Product number. That said, I need the running total to be calculated based on the product number. See below  **example code** and **current/desired output**.

**Note that the month field was left out, this is a test database that I created to see if some sample code that I found would work. Now I want to see if I can take it a bit further to provide the below desired output.**

**Example Code:**

```
SELECT Prod.Product, Prod.Amount, DSum("[Amount]","[Prod]","[Amount] >=" & [Amount]) AS RunTot, Prod.EndDate

FROM Prod

GROUP BY Prod.Product, Prod.Amount, Prod.EndDate;
```

**Desired Output - Example:**

Product  - SumOfAmount -RunTot -  month

7000XZ  - $600.00 -  600 - 10/28/14

7000XZ  - $500.00 - $1100 - 11/28/14

7000YT  - $400.00  - $400 - 10/28/14

7000YT  - $300.00 - $700 - 11/28/14

7000AB  - $200.00 - $200 - 10/28/14

7000AB  - $100.00 - $300- 11/28/14

7000WE  - $130.00 - $130 - 10/28/14

7000WE  - $121.00 - $251 - 11/28/14

**Current OutPut - Example:**

7000XZ  - $600.00 -  $600

7000XZ  - $500.00 - $1100

7000YT  - $400.00  - $1500

7000YT  - $300.00 - $1800

7000AB  - $200.00 - $2000

7000WE  - $130.00 - $2130

7000WE  - $121.00 - $2251

7000AB  - $100.00 - $2351

Current output Report:

I played around with the input provided and didn't get the desired input. Please take a look.

![Sample Report After flowing instruction at:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4?CTT=1&CorrelationId=4c1bcd05-6bab-4844-8d51-47111c6ab911&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmrunningsum][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IJBA.png)

Comment: How do you intend to use this query? As the Record Source for a report, perhaps?

Comment: Gord, That's correct.

Comment: Are you aware that you can [Calculate a running sum (cumulative total)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4?CTT=1&CorrelationId=4c1bcd05-6bab-4844-8d51-47111c6ab911&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmrunningsum) in an Access report?

Comment: By product (so that the report would have the Current month  and cumulative total) in the same report? If so, no I am not aware of how to do that. That information would be great.

Comment: @ghstarks Just use your current query without the SumOfAmount field. Then go to the Create tab -> Report (under Reports). Add a sort by going to the Design tab -> Group & Sort. Then hit the Add a Sort button on the bottom and select your Product field. Then you can follow the directions in the link above

Comment: Current output Report:

I played around with the input provided and didn't get the desired input. Please take a look.

![Sample Report After flowing instruction at: 

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4?CTT=1&CorrelationId=4c1bcd05-6bab-4844-8d51-47111c6ab911&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmrunningsum][1]